# How to create a bar graph with standard deviation and with facets with different X axes in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like:
[image]

I would like to generate barplots of the samples (Sample2) in relation to the counts (log) and create facets for each genus, as:
[image]

I used the following codes:

```
library (ggplot2)
library (ggpubr)
p <- ggbarplot (dataset, x = "Sample2", y = "log", add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),  add.params = list(shape = "Origin"), fill = "Origin", palette = c("orange", "blue", "red"),  ylim = c(5, 10))
p <- p + facet_grid(~Genera, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

But I obtained:
[image]

I couldn't find the answer to this issue. If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about ggpubr, but here is an outline how you can construct a similar barchart with vanilla ggplot2.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# I'm guessing this is roughly the shape of your data
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  Sample2 = rep(c(1:18), each = 5),
  log = rnorm(90, rep(rnorm(18), each = 5)) + 5,
  Genera = rep(c("Halomonas", "Pseudoalteromonas", "Psychrobacter"), each = 30)
)
df$Origin <- sample(c("Cheese", "Environmental", "Food"), 18, replace = TRUE)[df$Sample2]



ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(Sample2), log, fill = Origin)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = mean_se) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(~ Genera, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>